# request full screen in IE 10

Tags: javascript

I tried to used function below

```
function goFullscreen(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element.msRequestFullScreen) {
    element.msRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

I want Javascript support in IE 10 because the browser is running in IE 10 but request full screen only support IE 11. Is there any way that can support in IE 10?

Comment: As a side remark, and I know you probably don't have a word to say on this, but Microsoft stopped supporting IE10 a few weeks ago so I would suggest that you invest time in switching to a more recent version of IE rather than trying to get a 8 year old browser behave like a modern one.

Comment: [**Danger**](https://hub.packtpub.com/microsoft-announces-internet-explorer-10-will-reach-end-of-life-by-january-2020/): IE10 reached **end of life** in 2016. In January it ceased receiving security updates and technical support. **Do not use IE10**.

Comment: Other than using ActiveX or opening a new window to do it, not really.

Comment: how can I set IE 11 as default because when I access to website , it was default by IE 10

Answer (score 0):

No. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).

Experimental support for the fullscreen API was introduced in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods that will work for you, although it is very rudimental, is to use:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
myWindow.document.write("<p>I´m ready</p>");
```

You just have to pass the object with the html and the necessary functionality.
I hope it serves you

In my code I open directly the specific window and prepared for the functionality that I need

```
function openFullWindow(CTri) {

   if (window.name != 'salidas') {
       url_src = "test.asp?Indice=<%=indice%>&Numero=<%=numero%>&IdUser=<%=iduser%>&CodTribunal="+CTri;
       w=800;
       h=600;
       if (window.screen) {
           w = window.screen.availWidth;
           h = window.screen.availHeight;
       }
       manejadorVentana = window.open(url_src, "salidas", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,width="+w+",height="+h+",top=0,left=0");
    }
}
```

the event to launch from the big window to the small is window.opener